# Regex to find specific letters and extract the whole word

Tags: regex, expression

I want to find the word `ABC-` and if it matches, it will find the 6 numbers after the hyphen and the whole string must be inside the triangle bracket

Meaning in this whole paragraph, only `<ABC-123456>` will match the regex.

```
ABC123 Test ABCD-223 <ABC-123456> ABC-123456
```

Comment: What is the tool/programming language? What patterns have you tried?

Comment: if you just want to match `<ABC-` followed by 6 digits and `>`, then just use `<ABC-\d{6}>`

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/Y6Ez40/1

Comment: PHP. I tried:

(?:\/?<[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z].+)

Comment: Wonder what's the downvote for?:O

Comment: It is generally when the question is ambiguous/unclear and/or user havn't put what has he tried as of now. I see your other 2 questions, where you put some effort what have you tried. Hence no downvote there, but that seemed to be missing from here. PS: I didn't downvote it but whoever did, though the same. Also it is not always the case. I see some bad questions goes without downvoting. It is based on individual. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comment, use this

```
<ABC-\d{6}>
```

This will match `<ABC` followed by 6 digits and a `>`

Answer (score 0):

Demonstrated here - https://regex101.com/r/bATYi5/1

tl:dr   `(?'groupName'\<ABC\-\d{6}\>)`

(?'groupName'   ) is the group capture construct.
\ denotes a literal match
ABC denotes literally matching ABC
\d matches digits
{6} says match exactly 6 digits

You didn't specify which language you are using which means the group construct might need to be modified. The example site lets you choose the regex flavor to test against.